# texbox value is not showing in url

Tags: asp.net-mvc

i want to send text box value to controller in action as a 2nd parameter.
first parameter is id and second one is myval.
here is view code:

```
@model System.ValueTuple<System.Data.DataTable,websitetemplate.Models.ChartQuantity>
 <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 nopadding">
            <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">
                <div class="section-2-box-left wow fadeInLeft">
                    @if (Model.Item1.Rows.Count > 0)
                    {
                        string myimage = Model.Item1.Rows[0][4].ToString();


                        <div style="margin-bottom:10px; "><figure><img src="~/image/@myimage" /></figure></div>
                        <div style="margin-top:2px;">

                            <p>Title:@Model.Item1.Rows[0][1]</p>
                            <p>Description:@Model.Item1.Rows[0][2]</p>
                            <p>Price: $ @Model.Item1.Rows[0][3]</p>

                            <label>Quantity:</label>
                            @Html.TextBoxFor(model=>model.Item2.quantity, new { Type = "Number" })<br />


                        </div>
                     string val = Model.Item2.quantity.ToString();
                        <a href="@Url.Action("chart", "Chart", new { id = Model.Item1.Rows[0][0], myval=Model.Item2.quantity })" class="btn btn-primary">Add to chart</a>




                    }
                    else
                    {
                    <div>
                        <figure><img src="~/image/alt.jpg" /></figure>
                    </div>
                    }


                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is controller:

```
  public ActionResult chart(int id = 0, int myval = 0)
    {

        string val1="",val2="", val3 ="",val5="";
        int v=0;
        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection))
        {

            conn.Open();
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter("Select * from [dbo].[Admin] Where ID='" + id + "'", conn);
}
```

Here In View model.Item2.quantity is not passing properly in action link as it is not showing in controller. if any one know, please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Url.Action` helper method gets executed on the server when razor view engine is executing the code in your view. The result of that (HTML) will be send to the browser and then browser will render it. User can edit the value of the input element and there is no way that the `href` value of the already rendered link tag gets changed dynamically!

You have 2 options.

1) **Do a form submit**. You can wrap your input elements inside a form tag and do a form submit. When the form is submitted, it will send the current input element value as well. Make sure your input element `name` attribute value **matches your action method parameter name**.

```
<form action="chart" method="get">
    <input type="number" value="@Model.Item2.quantity" name="myval" />
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="@Model.Item1.Rows[0][0]" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn">Add to chart</button>
</form>
```

2) **Using JavaScript**. In this approach you will intercept the click event using JavaScript, stop the normal behavior (use `preventDefault` method to do so), read the input element value and build the URL with that values you want in that and navigate to that URl by setting the new URL to `window.location.href`.